# Keep azure spending limit or resources

Tags: azure

I have azure subscription with spending limit. Now, I need to add more then 5 users to VSTS - obviously I need to buy them. When I tried to buy more seats - marketplace asked to turn off spending limit. I am very frustrated. I am going to spend additional $12/month for two users, but they ask me do not care about money. I can't believe that, what if somebody steal my password and buy a lot of resources at the night?
Is there any other ways to limit monthly costs?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about billing.

Comment: You could approach it another way: Remove the spending limit, but enable multi-factor authentication on your Azure admin account so a stolen password is useless and, if it gives you more peace of mind, set an Azure policy in the subscription restricting the some very expensive resources (high end VMs, etc).

Comment: @Niels, thank you - it is something I already did. This is really hilarious that another 2 vsts places brings a LOT of headache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately you cannot achieve that without removing the spending limit.